# wifi p2p more than 2 peers group

Tags: android, wifip2p

I want to create a WiFiDirect group, using Wifi P2p android implementation, connecting more than 2 devices at the same time. Is it possible to generate the more than 2 devices group from the beginning using the WifiP2pManager.connect method, or is it necessary to first create the group  using the WifiP2pManager.createGroup method and then joining the group?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes it is possible to connect more than 2 devices. But you have to handle all the other devices on a separate thread for each device

Comment: How is it possible to create a 3 peers group it using WifiP2pManager.connect? I'm trying but I'm ending up with two different groups sharing one of the peers.